# Why is AVG picking up iTunes as a Trojan?

Tags: itunes, ipod, avg-antivirus

I just woke my computer (Windows Vista) from standby, plugged in my iPod Touch, and it complains that half of the iTunes DLLs are infected with the "Small.BOG" Trojan.

Anybody else seen similar? I believe I have the latest virus definitions.

Comment: 'cause it is :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just one of AVG many famous false positives, caused by its lastest definitions update.

Add exceptions to the resident shield if you want to use iTunes in the mean time until AVG fixes it.

```
Tools > Advanced settings... > Resident Shield > Exceptions
```

You probably want to add

```
C:\Program Files\iPod
C:\Program Files\iTunes
```

Obviously modify the path to where your program are actually installed.

Comment: More info here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2092831&tstart=0

Comment: That link was only 4 pages only 30 mins ago, now it's 6 (and increasing). lol

Comment: And my AVG post is growing. In fact an anti-AVG flame war has already started!

http://forums.avg.com/ww.avg-free-forum?sec=thread&act=show&id=7797

Comment: I switched to Avast.

Answer (score 1):

Further, I have followed the instructions on "what to do if you suspect a false positive" and informed AVG of the problem. http://forums.avg.com/ww.avg-free-forum?sec=thread&act=show&id=395

Answer (score 0):

Could be you do have a trojan. There is a listener, like Netcat, called Tini that is only 3KB. It is easy to wrap into other programs. Run a scan on the files before you add them to your exceptions list.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running full system scan using i.e. Malwarebytes´ Anti-Malware and/or Spybot Search & Destroy (remember to unplug your internet-connection and disable AVG).  It could be just another false-positive but you never know. If it seems to be false-positive, add iTunes installation folder to AVG´s exception list.